# Sorting fields in awk

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I need help sorting in awk.

Data:
BRAND MODEL YEAR MILEAGE PRICE

### input file

```
Toyota Camry 1999 120000 2000

Honda Civic 1990 100239 5000

Subaru Legacy 2003 72198 4300

Honda Accord 2008 80324 12839

Subaru WRX 2017 700 25000

Toyota Sienna 2005 75600 17832
```

This is the data given to me and I need to sort it by Price then mileage then year.

I have used `sort -k1,1b -k5,5n -k4,4n -k3,3n` gave me the output:

```
Honda Civic 1990 100239 5000

Honda Accord 2008 80324 12839

Subaru Legacy 2003 72198 4300

Subaru WRX 2017 700 25000

Toyota Camry 1999 120000 2000

Toyota Sienna 2005 75600 17832
```

### Desired Output

```
Honda Civic 1990 80324 5000

Honda Accord 2008 100239 12839

Subaru Legacy 2003 700 4300

Subaru WRX 2017 72198 25000

Toyota Camry 1999 75600 2000

Toyota Sienna 2005 120000 17832
```

The whole point is to basically sort the price, mileage, and year columns independently for each brand.

Comment: Welcome to SO, wrap your samples in CODE TAGS so that it will be better understandable for us, let me know on same then.

Comment: you sure that you didnt mix the desired with your out put file? it looks like the out put honda mileage  fits the original, but... the desired is different then original

Comment: It's just the mileage varying within brands...

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk, multi-dimensional arrays and [controlled scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc" # I hope numeric order works with text
}
{
    a[$1][$5][$4][$3]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in a)                          # brand
        for(j in a[i])                   # price
            for(k in a[i][j])            # mileage
                for(l in a[i][j][k])     # year
                    print a[i][j][k][l]
}' file
Honda Civic 1990 100239 5000
Honda Accord 2008 80324 12839
Subaru Legacy 2003 72198 4300
Subaru WRX 2017 700 25000
Toyota Camry 1999 120000 2000
Toyota Sienna 2005 75600 17832
```